# About windows azure blob storage, the implementation of a project should not depends on the cloud platform

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We plan to migrate the existing website to Windows azure, and i have been told that we need to store files to blob storage.
My questions is:
If we want to use blob storage, that means i need to re-write the file storage function(we use file system for now), call blob service api to store files, that's very strange for me just because we want to use windows azure, how about in the future we want to use Amazon EC2 or other cloud platform, they might have there own way to store file, then may be i need to re-write the file storage function again, in my opinion , the implementation of a project should not depends on the cloud platform(or cloud server)! Can any body correct me, thanks!

Comment: You are correct in that its nice to abstract this out, the devil is in the details however.  You might be interested in an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't address the commentary about whether an app should have a dependency on a particular cloud environment (or specific ways to deal with that particular issue), as that's subjective and it's a nice debate to have somewhere else. What I *will* address is the actual storage in Azure, as your info is a bit out-of-date.

One reason to use blob storage directly (and possibly the reason you were told to use blob storage) is that it provides access from multiple instances of your app. Also, blob storage provides 500TB of storage per storage account, and it's triple-replicated within the deployed region (and optionally geo-replicated). With attached storage (either with local disk or blob-backed Azure Disk), the access is specific to a particular instance of your app. Shifting from file system access to blob storage access does require app modification.

If you choose not to modify your app's file I/O operations, then you can also consider the new Azure File Service, which provides SMB access to storage (backed by blob storage). Using File Service, your app would (hopefully) not need to be modified, although you might need to change your root path.

More information on Azure File Service may be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot, i already use adapter to re-write the file storage functions, and may be i think too much in this case, sometimes may be just need to compare the advantage and disadvantage, then decide to use it or, it would be perfect if there's no dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it seem strange? You need to store your files somewhere and the cloud is a good a place as any **IF** it suits your needs. The obvious advantages are redundancy and geo replication, sharing files across multiple projects and servers, The list goes on.  It's difficult to advise on whether it would be a good idea or not without hearing some specifics.

You could use windows azure storage with amazon in the future if you wanted to (you'd just need to set up the access for it), obviously with slighter longer delay.  Then again that slight performance drop may be significant and you may end up re-writing it.

Most importantly, swapping over from one cloud provider to another is not trivial depending on just how much you use it or how much data you've got in it, so I would strongly suggest looking at the advantages / disadvantages of each platform closely before putting your lot in with either one and then fully learn that platform.

Personally, I went for Azure cloud services + storage etc even though it was slightly more expensive at the time, because i'm a Microsoft Person (not that I didn't do my research). It was annoying in the early days when key features were missing, but it's really matured now and I like the pace that it's improving.

It's cheap to test, why not try both and see which one suits you? A small price to pay when you have big decisions to make.

Disclaimer: I don't know the current state of Amazon web services.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i knew there's a lots of benefit to use blob storage, and the Amazon cloud platform is just a example in this case, i'm not saying blob storage is not good, actually , i'm totally agree with what you said, but my point is that: this time we call blog service api to store file, may be in future, we have other nice cloud platform or new server technology, then the file storage function of project need to change again.

Comment: Unfortunately that's true of all technology no? In my opinion it would boil down to speed, reliability and cost (perhaps having a terrible API might be hindrance). They want to hook you in now so that you can't be bothered to move all your data/projects when the latest and greatest comes along. A lot of this decision making is trusting in your provider to stay the course, i'm fairly confident that Microsoft will be in that race so i'm happy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. We are in the middle of a migration of an old PHP/MySQL/LocalShare to WebRole/SQLAzure/AzureStorage ERP application. We faced the same problem and decision. Let me write some thoughts about the issue :

It is a good option to just be able to switch the storage provider but is it reasonable? You can always build the abstraction but do you plan how to do the actual change of storage provider - migration/sync while in production? What kind of argument will exactly drive the transition to another storage provider? How much users and data do you have? Do you plan to shard-rebalance the storage in the future? How reliable must be this system during this storage provider switch? Do you want to totally move the data when you want to switch or you just want to shard it so that you start using this different provider? Does the cost development of these (reliable) storage layers and the cost of development of reliable transitions (or bi-directional syncs) outweighs the money difference between any two storage providers?

Just switching storage mechanism from Azure Blob to Amazon will incur heavy latency penalty if your other services are on Azure - When you create Storage and Services on Azure you set affinity groups by region so that you minimize the network latency.

These are only a few of the questions to answer before doing all the weightlifting. We have abstracted the file repository (blob) because we planned to move from local NFS to Blob transparently and gradually and it answers our needs.